# Binomial theorem for exponential of nilpotent matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, binomial-theorem

**Question Statement**

A matrix $N \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is called *nilpotent* if there exist $k$ such that $N^{k} = 0 \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. The smallest such $k$ is called the *index* of $N$. 
Let $$ A = \lambda I + N$$

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N$ is nilpotent of index $k$. Obtain a simple (that is easy to compute ) formula for the matrix exponential $e^{At}$.

**Attempt at solution** 
\begin{align*}
e^{At} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}(\lambda I +N)^{k} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{n} (\lambda I)^{k-n} N^{n} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{n! (k-n)!} \lambda^{k-n} N^{n} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{k-n}t^{n}}{(k-n)!n!} \lambda^{k-n}N^{n} \\
&\text{Letting $ m = k -n $  we get } \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m=0}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{m!} \lambda^{m} \frac{N^n t^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} e^{\lambda t} \frac{N^{n}t^n}{n!} 
\end{align*}
I don't know how to proceed from here or if my solution makes sense in the first place.

Comment: why did you use the binomial theorem?  Unless you were told it is required, a better path is to note for commuting matrices the exponential splits just like in the scalar case-- i.e $e^{At}=e^{t(\lambda  I +  N)}=e^{\lambda t I}e^{t N}$.  Being Nilpotent you can write out and immediately truncate the power series for $e^{t N}$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm confused, what do you mean by "truncate the power series for $e^{tN}$" ?  Do you mean like just removing the last term of the Taylor series since at the final value of $k$ , $N^k =0$ ? Thank you.

Comment: basically for nilpotent $N$ with index k, you formally have $e^{N} = I + \sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{N^r}{r!}$.  However by nilpotence of $N$ you know all but finitely many terms are zero, and in particular all terms where $r\geq k$ are zero  so you can truncate the infinite series and just write  $e^{N} = I + \sum_{r=1}^{k-1} \frac{N^r}{r!}$